How can we import PBIX file on powerbi workspace using Powershell
When I'm running this powershell code to import a PBIX file getting error
 {
  "Code": "InputStreamIncorrectLengthException", "message": "The length of the file input does not match the provided length"
 }

$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $token"
    "Content-Type"  = "multipart/form-data"
    "X-PowerBI-Profile-ID" = $profileId
}
 
# Read the PBIX file content
$fileContent = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($pbixFilePath)

$boundary = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
 
# Create the multipart/form-data content

$content = "--$boundary`r`n" +
           "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"file`"; filename=`"$(Split-Path -Leaf $pbixFilePath)`"`r`n" +

           "Content-Type: application/octet-stream`r`n`r`n" +

           [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($fileContent) + "`r`n" +
           "--$boundary--"
 
# API endpoint for importing the PBIX file

$importUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/$workspaceId/imports?datasetDisplayName=$(Split-Path -Leaf $pbixFilePath)"
 
# Make the POST request to import the PBIX file
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $importUrl -Headers $headers -Body $content


you content type is multipart/form which is mime.  See following what a MIME message should look like : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)  Each MIME attachment starts with tow dashes on a new line.  Your error indicates the size of one of the MIME attachments is wrong
